# Cannot load css/js for html loaded from Ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, cgi

I am using CGI scripting for a very small application where I send a request to a DB from a text box and receive some data and display it on the same web page. I have the following HTML for the text box page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Text Search</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function xmlhttpPost() {
        var xmlHttpReq = false;
        var self = this;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        self.xmlHttpReq.open("POST", "test2.py", true);
        self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
                updatepage(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText);
            }
        }
        self.xmlHttpReq.send(getquerystring());
    }
    function getquerystring() {
        var form = document.forms["search_form"];
        var word = form.word.value;
        qstr = 'q=' + escape(word);
        alert(qstr);
        return qstr;
    }
    function updatepage(str){
        alert(str);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
    }
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="search_form">
    <p>
        Query: <input name="word" type="text">
        <input value="Submit" type="button" onclick='JavaScript:xmlhttpPost()'>
    </p>
    <div id="result">
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

As soon as I submit the text, I receive a `<table>...</table>` like

```
<table width=100% height=100%>
<tr>
<td width=80%>
<div id="tabs" style="width: 1200px;">
    <ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-151802">donald</a></li></ul>
<div id="tabs-151802">

<div id="1" class="151802">
<h2>1.  Index of World War II articles (D) - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</h2><br>
<a href=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_World_War_II_articles_(D) target="_blank">http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_World_War_II_articles_(D)</a><br><br>
</div>
<hr>
</div>

</div>
</td>
<td width=20% valign="top" style="font-size: initial;">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

from `test2.py` which is displayed between `<div id="result"></div>`. The application is working fine but I cannot get the CSS/JS to work for the content I receive! I wish to use the same scripts (js/css) as in the HTML for the query page.

The css/js works correctly if I render the page without an ajax call.

UPDATE:
I noticed that the CSS is not being loaded. The javascript can be ignored a of now. The `style.css` has `font-family` and `font-size` for `body`. None of these are loaded.

Comment: Where is `css/js` in your current page ?

Comment: @RayonDabre In the first part there are two `<script>` and one `<link>`. Those are the one I wish to use

Comment: `css` file you have added is only setting style for `body`

Comment: Should I add the css/js links to the html content loaded fromm ajax?

Comment: That is not necessary. For `js`, you need to initialize required methods once external `DOM`  is loaded

Comment: Why don't you simply include your `<script>` and `<link>` in the new page?

Comment: @Sina I have uploaded the question. Including that is also not helping.

Comment: So, just to clarify this, the inline CSS loads fine (as you have shown in the `<table>`)and the external CSS and JS files don't seem to load? Are you including them in your call as well to be loaded?

Comment: In the first snippet the `updatepage(str)` function has the whole content that has to be displayed. `str` is then added to the innerhtml. This is content is the second snippet.